# How to remove all rows excpet the certain values exit in certain columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like below:

```
    Text          column_1        column_2
0   string            1             0
1   string            0             1
2   .....             ..           ..
```

I want to remove all rows from `df` if `column_1` and `column_2` contains any values other than 0/1.

That means in my final dataframe `column_1` and `column_2` should only conatain `0` and `1`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) for select values in filtered columns with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for both `True`s and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df[['column_1','column_2']].isin([0,1]).all(axis=1)]
```

If possible values are also strings:

```
df = df[df[['column_1','column_2']].isin([0,1,'0','1']).all(axis=1)]
```